# Velocity.js | Transform scale first animation ignored

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I have a simple div which have a css property `scale(.8)` and when hovering this div I'm using `velocity.js` to scale it to (1), however the first animation is ignored. I m aware that velocity.js use forcefeeding so that it erase the css animation but in that case I don t know how I can make it work..
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**https://jsfiddle.net/xtkak17y/15/**

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

```
  $elem = $('.section');
    $elem.hover(
        function() {
            $elem.velocity({ 
                scale: [1, 0.8]
            }, 300, "ease-in-out");
        }, function() {
            $elem.velocity({ 
                scale: [0.8]
            }, 300, "ease-in-out");
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xtkak17y/18/